# Unable to import pip modules in python 3.11.5

Tags: python, python-import

I am pretty new to python and have no formal computer science training so sorry in advance if this is unclear.

I am using Windows 10, I'm unable to import any modules that were installed via pip. The warning I get in Visual Studio is "Import 'Module' could not be resolved." This is only applying to modules that were installed using pip. The default library seems to work fine.

For whatever reason pip seems to be installing files in a different directory. Pip is installing packages at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages`, while Python is installed at `C:\Program Files\Python311`. I initially thought that might be the problem, but checking `sys.path` (below) it still shows the appropriate path to where pip is installing packages.

```
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']
```

All of the pip packages are in that second from the last directory. So as far as I can tell it is looking there for them. But it still doesn't seem to be able to import them.

The project I'm working on is also stored at `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\...` which might be causing an issue? But I'm not sure where else to keep it. Anyway, I appreciate any help.

> Import keyboard
>
> Warning (active)  reportMissingImports    Import "keyboard" could not be
> resolved

I have tried running a section of the script just in case it's just a Visual Studio issue, but it doesn't seem to work. Right now all I have are the three lines below and it's still not working.

```
import bs4    
print("Hello World")
input()
```

```
UPDATE:

Did the completely fresh install as suggested. Python installed itself into a new directory. It is now at 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312

But at least pip is installing to the "right" directory now.

    >>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
    ['',
     'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib',
     'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312',
     'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages']

However, I am still getting the same error, this doesn't seem to have fixed anything. Still the same Error in Visual Studio, and still can't run even a very basic print() unless I remove the import line.
```

Comment: That seems to be a linter warning. Have you tried running the script and seeing if Python itself gives you an error? If it's fine, then the problem is with Visual Studio. I haven't used it myself so IDK what the cause might be. Maybe check that it's using the same Python interpreter?

Comment: Try running the script both via VS and outside; that'd give you more details.

Comment: It's odd that `sys.path` contains two different site-packages folders.  Did you add one of those to the path yourself?

Comment: In this case, I think creating a new virtual environment, activating the virtual environment, and downloading the required libraries might solve your issue.

Comment: @JohnGordon no, I have not manually added any paths. Pip/python has done made all of those paths automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In your case i suggest you to fully uninstall Python and reinstall it.
Also delete folder python in `C:\Users\User\AppData\\Local\Programs`

Dont forget to check "Add to path" when you install python and dont change anything else.

Then when you begin a new project i hihgly recommend to create `venv` to install only the required packages.

How to do it in VSCode -> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

How to do it in PyCharm -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

More information on what id a `venv` and why you should use it -> [https://csguide.cs.princeton.edu/software/virtualenv#:~:text=Always%20use%20a%20Virtual%20Environment,-Always.&text=Virtual%20environments%20let%20you%20have,many%20venvs%20as%20you%20want](https://csguide.cs.princeton.edu/software/virtualenv#:%7E:text=Always%20use%20a%20Virtual%20Environment,-Always.&text=Virtual%20environments%20let%20you%20have,many%20venvs%20as%20you%20want).